# arcgis-android-100.3.0.pom says Forbidden

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

We are try to make sample sample app as mentioned here

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm

Whenever we try to build, we get below error.

Could not GET 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-android/100.3.0/arcgis-android-100.3.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Any idea why this is happening?

Note : I tried with `100.0.0` or `100.9.0` also, but same error.

Also note, I can access below link
http://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-android/100.9.0/, but when I click on pom or aar file, it says Forbidden.

Am I missing anything?